# Где границы у принципа единой ответственности (single responsibility principle)?

Tags: шаблоны-проектирования, activerecord, solid

Существует такой паттерн как ActiveRecord. Известно, что он нарушает принцип единой ответственности. Например:

```
$user = new User();
$user->name('My Name');
$user->save();
```

Метод save содержит код для сохранения данных в базу, таким образом нарушая принцип. Другой пример:

```
$file = new File('myfile.txt');
$file->save();
```

Он так же содержит метод save, но так как взаимодействие происходит с одной обязанностью, принцип не нарушается. Еще пример:

```
$dir = new Dir('mydir');
$dir->delete();
```

Чтобы удалить директорию, надо рекурсивно удалить вложенные файлы и директории. Нарушается ли принцип единой ответственности здесь? И как определить где он нарушается?

Comment: $dir->delete(); - в яве, шарпе, плюсах подобное удаление работает только на пустых дирректориях. Думаю, такой подход есть во многих языках. Что конкретно тут нарушается?

Comment: Это абстрактный пример. И ниже я пояснил, что он должен рекурсивно удалять содержимое. Речь не о стандартных функциях и методах в каком-либо языке